# Realistic Embossed Effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

[image][image]

Anyone please help me how to make the embossed effect as in the image. Is it made by 3D software or photoshop? Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=create+shadowed+3+D+text+in+Photoshop

Comment: ^ I hope the OP goes to that search results page. Lots of great tutorials right on top!

Comment: That's not what most would call 'embossed'. Rather, it's emulating an actual 3D object with a cast shadow.

Comment: @DA01 yea, the closest to embossed that my brain allows me to get, is like the backside of a silicon mold.

Comment: Curiously, this question is now the #1 search result for "realistic embossed effect" on google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I gave it a try to see how it's done in under 5 minutes and I came up with this:

- Make a background layer and give it a color
- Select **Type Tool** and write a letter *(works better if the font weight is bold)*
- Give that letter a slightly darker tone of the background color
- Right click on the text layer -> **Blending Options** -> **Bevel and Embross**

  - In the image below I had the following settings:

    - Depht **65%**
    - Direction **Up**
    - Size **1**
    - Soften **0**
    - Highlight Mode - **Color Dodge** at **70% white**
    - Shadow Mode - **Soft Light** at **100% black**
- Make the same letter but with black color
- Flatten it, place it under the first one and move it halfway in the direction of where you want the shadow (mine is bottom-right)
- Go to **Filter** tab -> **Blur** -> **Motion blur** and select the direction of the shadow and the distance that best suits your design.
- Go to **Filter** tab -> **Blur** -> **Gaussian Blur** and give it a bit of **Radius** just to make it look better.
- Final step: Set the layer's **Blending Mode** to **Soft Light**.

[image]

- It also helps to check the **Contour** box from under **Bevel and Embross** in the **Blending Options**.
- Also, Adding a small **Inner Shadow** will help too.

  - in this image I used:

    - **15% opacity** with **Soft Light** as Blending Mode
    - Distance **5**
    - Choke **0**
    - Size **30**

[image]

> PS: In my example I used **[Lato Ultra Bold](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Lato)** at **500pt**.

### One more thing

---

If you wanna go completely crazy with it, you can go ahead and add a **second shadow**, but less opaque, just ass seen on the text effect from your link:

[image]

Another thing about this text effect is that the shadow is sharper on the edges, for this just don't do the Gaussion Blur step.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's really helpful! I'll give it a try soon and maybe write some feedback or question about it :) Thanks again.

Comment: When I look closely, I find that on the top edges of letter "B", there are some white light that make me feel like the letter has a light source on the top.

Do you know how to create that light? Thank you! @Alin

Comment: @user53891 If you think about it a little, it's basically the same principle as with the shadows, just change the black to white and erase the areas where you don't want the glow.

Comment: @user53891 This could be a question that other could benefit from, would you mind editing your question with things you tried before and so on so that we can re-open it ?

Comment: I just join this website to ask this question so I'm not sure what you want me to do?

Comment: @user53891 Nothing, it's fine, if you're considering becoming an active member of this website, before asking other question please see these guidelines on how to ask a good question in order to avoid downvoting or closing : http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hey @Alin, I just add an image from behance to my question above. Have a look :) The colors and shadows are stunning..

Comment: Hellow there @user53891 , it does look nice, you can also achieve this with the technique described in my answer, the tools are the same. Next to the technique above, you can also do these using PS's 3D, Illustrator and so on. What I'm trying to say is that this can be done in a lot of ways. The one I described is the easiest to understand while using pretty common tools.Best of lick!

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be made in Photoshop.

1. Make a new Photoshop file.
2. Make a background to your liking - there are plenty if you google them.
3. Write text and rasterize layer.
4. On the layers panel, set the fill to 0%.
5. Right-click the text and click Blending Options.
6. Copy these effects in.
   [image: I'st one]
   [image: 2nd one]
   You might need to adjust these effects to your background.
   The final result can be found here.

[image]

Let me know if you need any more info.